# counter is not resetting at end of the each iteration of the loop controller in jmeter

Tags: while-loop, jmeter, counter

I want to reset my counter at end of the each iteration of the loop. I implemented solution in my script like in the page 
[Jmeter - Loop counter in while loop not resetting on exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45964303/jmeter-loop-counter-in-while-loop-not-resetting-on-exit/58538178#58538178)
but given solution is not working for me . I am using `apache jmeter 5.1.1` version I added below code in `JSR223` sampler out side the while controller within transaction controller

```
def counter=vars.get("counter"); ${__groovy(vars.put('counter'\, '2'),)}
```

Counter

[image]

Counter value is resetting but updated counter value not carrying to second iteration

```
logs: 2019-10-24 14:53:53,281 INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.J.JSR223 Sampler: counter value-----2
```

Placed JSR223 Sampler outside while `controller/trasaction controller/loop controller..` In all the ways it is giving same response like below

[image]

I need result as

```
xrequest-1 

xrequest-2 

xrequest-3 

xrequest-4 

xrequest-5 

xrequest-6 

xrequest-7 

xrequest-8 . . . 

yrequest-1 

yrequest-2 

yrequest-3 

yrequest-4 

yrequest-5 

yrequest-6 . . .
```

Please help me if i am missing anything.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need any Counter there.

Since [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5/) [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) exposes a special [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which looks like:

```
${__jm__While Controller__idx}
```

where `While Controller` needs to match the While Controller label.

So if you need to count iterations - you can just refer this variable. It's zero-based, to wit the value will be `0` at the first iteration, if you need the iteration number to start with `1` - go for [__intSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) like:

```
${__intSum(${__jm__While Controller__idx},1,)}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working perfectly for my script